# Should I use custom data elements as parameter holders for event handling in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a project, I was invoking events from in-line codes. 
**Old usage;**

```
<button id='button' onclick='do_stuff("<?= $id ?>", "<?= $name ?>")'>Do</button>
```

But now, I want to use event listeners. **New usage;**

```
$('#button').click({id:'<?= $id ?>', name:'<?= $name ?>'}, item_event_handler);

function item_event_handler(event)
{
  var id = event.data.id;
  var name = event.data.name;

  do_stuff(id, name);
}

function do_stuff(id, name)
{
}
```

This one works. But here is the problem; let's say I'm listing some items like below and I want to add event listeners on those items. **Current usage;**

```
<ul>
  <? foreach($items as $item): ?>
  <li class='item' onclick='do_stuff("<?= $item->id ?>", "<?= $item->name ?>")'>
    <?= $item->title ?>
  </li>
  <? endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Since *I don't want to create those items with JavaScript*, I can't add event listeners to them with individual parameters. Should I use data attributes to fetch parameters? **Like;**

```
$('.item').click(item_event_handler);

function item_event_handler(event)
{
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var name = $(this).data('name');

  do_stuff(id, name);
}

<ul>
  <? foreach($items as $item): ?>
  <li class='item' data-id='<?= $item->id ?>' data-name='<?= $item->name ?>'>
    <?= $item->title ?>
  </li>
  <? endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Is this approach alright to use or there is any other way that makes more sense? Using data attributes in this manner could point to future problems? I don't want to waste time or make it complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid mixing php and javascript by using  `data-` attributes in markup and use `data()` method to read them

HTML

```
<li class="item" data-id="<?= $item->id ?>" data-name="<?= $name ?>">
```

JS

```
$('#button').click( item_event_handler);

function item_event_handler(event)
{
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var name = $(this).data('name');

  do_stuff(id, name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `data-*`attributes to store data on the elements and you can access those data easily with jquery.

**edit:** you should access them like this:

```
$(selector).attr('data-id');
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to bind the click event to the items ... either you can call your function or do watever you want inside

`$("body").on("click","item" function(event){
item_event_handler();
});`